# Qt 5.1.1 and OpenGL - rendering speed

Tags: c++, windows, qt, opengl

I created my OpenGL application based on following Qt classes: QWindow, QOpenGLContext, QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core. I use QTimer for rendering the scene:

```
QTimer* timer = new QTimer( this );
connect( timer, SIGNAL( timeout() ), this, SLOT( renderScene() ) );
timer->start( ms );
```

When ms = 0 I can check max FPS. The result is ~2200 fps (v-sync off) but when I want to resize a window using mouse the program hangs up. Then I have to use “ctrl+ alt + del” and kill the process manually (a debugger doesn’t contain any message). What might be wrong ?

I also wonder why I get 64 fps when a timer interval is set to 1 (should be 1000 fps). Other results: interval = 10 also 64 fps, interval = 50 -> 16 fps, interval = 100 -> 9 fps. Only the last result (100 ms -> 9fps) seems to be correct. How to explain those results ?

Comment: do you resize the glcontext to the new size?

Comment: Yes:  connect( this, SIGNAL( widthChanged( int ) ), this, SLOT( resizeGL() ) );
    connect( this, SIGNAL( heightChanged( int ) ), this, SLOT( resizeGL() ) ); For timer interval > 0 resizing works fine.

Comment: when a QTimer's timeout is 0 then it will bypass the OS message queue and be called each time there is no other event to process, the os queue will generally impose a lot of overhead

Comment: I use Freeglut in my other OpenGL application and I can resize a window when the program works with max fps, so is it possible to achieve that in Qt ?

Comment: As the documentation tells you, QTimer has a certain overhead. Don't use it, use QObject::startTimer() instead. In any case, I have the feeling you are using OpenGL in the wrong way. Did you read the Qt OpenGL documentation? Does it say to use timers to do the rendering?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are on windows, given the fact that you close the program using

```
ctrl+ alt + del
```

When `ms = 0` you are indeed measuring the performance of processing `renderScene()` in using events as fast as possible. When a Qtimer times out, it queues an `QTimerEvent`. Your timer keep timing out and queuing `QTimerEvent` and flooding the event queue. When you resize the window, a resize event is placed on the queue full of timer events, and will be processed only after those events. Because the event is not processed by the application in time, the application appears irresponsive

When `ms != 0` your measurements are inaccurate because the operating system timer is inaccurate. When I was developing a multi-platform player, I noticed that on ***my windows any time delay from 1ms to 15 ms was around 15 ms***, [something which can be tested directly](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/08/windows-timer-resolution-megawatts-wasted/). If you run your same test on linux, you will see a better fps for 1ms than 10 ms (still 1ms resolution is not  guaranteed)

So to wrap up:

- The difference in your test results has nothing to do with Open-GL
- The difference in your test results has a lot to do with Windows
- Timing differences in OS and OS versions are good reasons to have an external device to generate timecodes
- If you need a zero delay timer in a real program (and you may well be) it need to operate in a different event queue than the main event queue.

***Edit :*** The argument above for `ms != 0` is valid for Qt 4.8, and for the default `TimerType` (`Qt::CoarseTimer`) in Qt 5. You can use `setTimerType(Qt::PreciseTimer)` for millisecond accuracy, but [it is not guaranteed to succeed](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qt.html#TimerType-enum) :

> On Windows, Qt will use Windows's Multimedia timer facility (if
>   available) for Qt::PreciseTimer and normal Windows timers for
>   Qt::CoarseTimer and Qt::VeryCoarseTimer.